# Angular karma font awesome - SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, font-awesome, angular-cli

I am trying to setup font awesome in karma tests but that populates the following error

`Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
  at node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2:1`

Even with that error present, normal test execution (`ng test`) works fine as this just gets ignored. 
That doesn't apply though when i run a headless test (`ng test --browsers='PhantomJS' --single-run=true`) which breaks my automated build pipeline.

I am using Angular 4, created by angular/cli and in order to get font-awesome working in my tests i added the following in karma.conf.js

```
files: [
  { pattern: './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2*', watched: false },
  { pattern: './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff*', watched: false },
  { pattern: './node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf*', watched: false },
  { pattern: './node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css', watched: false },  
],
```

Based on my research so far, this error occurs because of the appended version (e.g. ?v=4.4.0) while font awesome css fetches files. 
I would be able to fix it by setting up custom loaders in webpack.

But, since angular/cli hides this implementation, I cannot seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

For me it simply worked adding:

```
files: [
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
  {
    pattern: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*',
    watched: false,
    included: false,
    served: true,
    nocache: false
  }
]
```

To `karma.conf.js` - icons displayed.